# Array order - Array group

Tags: php, arrays

i'm trying to sort an array in specific order:

My code (current Array):

```
Array
(
[25] => Array
    (
        [1st place] => 
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [2nd place] => 
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [3rd place] => 
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [4th place] => 
        [5th place] => 
        [6th place] => 
        [7th place] => 
        [8th place] => 
        [9th place] => 
        [10th place] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [11th place] => 
        [12th place] => 
        [13th place] => 
        [14th place] => 
        [15th place] => 
        [16th place] => 
        [17th place] => 
        [18th place] => 
        [19th place] => 
        [20th place] => 
        [21st place] => 
        [22nd place] => 
        [23rd place] => 
        [24th place] => 
        [25th place] => 
    )

)
```

Require Array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [1st place] => 25
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [2nd place] => 15
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [3rd place] => 10
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [4th place] => 5
        [5th place] => 5
        [6th place] => 5
        [7th place] => 5
        [8th place] => 5
        [9th place] => 5
        [10th place] => 5
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [11th place] => 1
        [12th place] => 1
        [13th place] => 1
        [14th place] => 1
        [15th place] => 1
        [16th place] => 1
        [17th place] => 1
        [18th place] => 1
        [19th place] => 1
        [20th place] => 1
        [21st place] => 1
        [22nd place] => 1
        [23rd place] => 1
        [24th place] => 1
        [25th place] => 1
    )

)
```

The idea is like use the Array position (?) as value of the key and set the array in this order:

I'm trying with that code (php)

```
foreach ($newOptions as $ord) {
            $place = $ord[$idx];
            $value = $ord[$idx][0];
            $newOrderarr[$idx][$value][$place] = $name2;
            $idx++;
        }
```

But is nor working fine $newoptions is the Array that i'm using for...

Comment: What about fixing data strucure first (not to mention index like "4th place" makes much less sense than just "4"

Comment: what's the point in doing it like this? wouldn't it be much easier to just do: $arr[0]=25; $arr[1]=15; $arr[2]=10;....

Comment: yes the problem is this is a dinamyc array, de values can change, so the idea is create something dinamically.

Comment: Ditch that data structure. Seriously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try this:

```
foreach($your_array as $key => &$bla) {
    foreach($bla as &$item) {
        $item = $key;
    }
}

sort($your_array);
```

But I'd rather fix the data structure to begin with, it seems at least... odd.

Comment: Sweet. I like this. I did something similar, but without the pass by reference. Never thought of that. +1 for conserving memory by not creating a new array. :)

Comment: Short and Sweet! just work perfect! TY!

Answer (score 5):

Nobody went with the obvious sorting method?

```
uasort($data, function($a, $b) {
    reset($a);
    reset($b);
    $aVal = (int) key($a);
    $bVal = (int) key($b);

    if ($aVal < $bVal) {
        return -1;
    } elseif ($bVal < $aVal) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Note that this resets the internal pointers in the sub-arrays, but that isn't likely to be a problem and they might be copies anyway.  Also, if you have an empty sub-array in there it wouldn't work.  In that case I'd simply call `array_filter` on it first to remove the empty values.

Comment: I did it in 8 lines of simple code 2 hours ago, and you are getting upvoted?

Comment: @keyboardSmasher You did say you didn't have time to test yours.  I not only tested mine but listed out what potential problems there might me and how to fix them.

Comment: Good for you, I'll give you your first legitimate upvote. Cheers.
+1 from me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see how you end up with your array structure, but if there is a strong reason to have it this way, you can do your sorting like this:

```
#recreating your data:
$newOptions = array();
$newOptions[25] = array('1st place' => '');
$newOptions[15] = array('2nd place' => '');
$newOptions[10] = array('3rd place' => '');
$newOptions[5] = array('4th place' => '', '5th place' => '', '6th place' => '', '7th place' => '', '8th place' => '', '9th place' => '', '10th place' => '');
$newOptions[1] = array('11th place' => '', '12th place' => '', '13th place' => '', '14thth place' => '', '15thth place' => '', '16th place' => '', '...' => '');

#sorting as you wanted
$newArray = array();
foreach ($newOptions as $id => $options) {
   $newOptions = $options;
   foreach ($newOptions as $optid => $option) {
      $newOptions[$optid] = $id;
   }
   $newArray[] = $newOptions;
}
$newOptions = $newArray;
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is the array is dinamically, sometimes the places or the Prizes (first number in the array) can changes, that is why i cant set the order direct in the code. sometimes this number [25] => Array could be 10 or 20, so i have order it Desc the first number always will be the greater.

Comment: My first few lines were only to test the following code. Which numbers are used does not matter for the seconde part. But I (and it seems anyone else) don't get, what you want to do - and where your initial array comes from.

Comment: i get the array from an external data provider, i have convert each array key in the value of the sub item and change the key for a natural order, for instance if the value is 15 and there are 10 places that pays 15 / in you code it order the array but not group by places...

Answer (score 1):

Your structure doesn't make sense to me? I've opted for something slightly different but hopefully will suit your needs just fine!

```
<?php
$scores = array(15, 20, 50, 100, 4);
sort($scores);

for($i = 0; $i < count($scores); $i++) {
    $new_array[] = array('score' => $scores[$i], 'text' => ordinal($i + 1) . " Place");
}

print_r($new_array);




// Ordinal from PHP docs
function ordinal($i = '') {
  $o=$i;
  $s=array('th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd');

  if(!is_int($o))
    if(ctype_digit($o))
      $o=(int)substr($o,-2,2);
    else
      return(false);
  return($i.$s[($o%100>10&&$o%100<20)?0:($o%10<4?$o%10:0)]);
}
```

This produces the output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [score] => 4
            [text] => 1st Place
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [score] => 15
            [text] => 2nd Place
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [score] => 20
            [text] => 3rd Place
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [score] => 50
            [text] => 4th Place
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [score] => 100
            [text] => 5th Place
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is the array is dinamically, sometimes the places or the Prizes (first number in the array) can changes, that is why i cant set the order direct in the code. sometimes this number [25] => Array could be 10 or 20, so i have order it Desc the first number always will be the greater.

Comment: That's why I use sort() - the values do not matter.

Comment: i see, but the problem is your $scores array has diferent structure than mine, i mean, i just recieve the array $newOptions exactly like i put in my example, how can i adapt your script to works with a multidimensional array like mine?

Comment: The problem being that your array doesn't offer any use. All we know is that whomever scored 25 points was first ... but then 7 people scores 5 and they're a variety of places? How do you decide which? I'd look to get something more useful from the orignal array

Comment: the array is grouping the places for instances the first number 25 means the prize and the content in it are the places, that means the 4th position in my array pays 1point to the places 11-12-13-14-15-16, i will use that data to show the prize table gruping and not show 11th - 1pt / 12th-1pt / 13th - 1pt / 14th - 1pt -- instead of that i will show 11th to 16th - 1pt

Answer (score 1):

```
$newOrderarr = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($newOptions as $k => $v){
    foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2){
        $newOrderarr[$i][$k2] = $k;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Didn't have time to test it, though.

Comment: it works, but not like i need, the idea is use the same group structure as i use but modify the index of each array in order [0,1,2,3] not like i have right now and then add the index of each array inside them, like the example i put.